# Save Web Service variable into MuleSoft Message

Tags: java, rest, mule, mule-studio

I have an http endpoint redirecting to a REST Java web service.
I am receiving a application/x-www-form-urlencoded request with some attributes embedded within the body of the request.

Inside the web service I would like to update the mule message status with those attributes.
Since RequestContext.getEventContext() is now deprecated and Doc says to implement Callable instead, however seems not working to me.The onCall method is never invoked.

Any idea ?

Below my code:

```
enter code here

    @Path("/restClass")
    public class HelloREST implements Callable{
    private String industry;
    private String lob;
    private String nuixlegalentity;
    private org.apache.log4j.Logger log = Logger.getLogger(LoadClass.class);

@POST
@Path("/setPayload")
@Consumes("application/x-www-form-urlencoded")
public void setMessage(@FormParam("industry") String industryParam, @FormParam("lob") String lobParam,@FormParam("nuixlegalentity") String nuixlegalentityParam){

    log.debug("**************INSIDE SETMESSAGE******************");

    industry=industryParam;
    lob=lobParam;
    nuixlegalentity=nuixlegalentityParam;


}
@Override 
public Object onCall(MuleEventContext eventContext) throws Exception{

    log.debug("**************INSIDE ONCALL******************");

    eventContext.getSession().setProperty("industry","industry");
    eventContext.getSession().setProperty("lob",lob);
    eventContext.getSession().setProperty("nuixlegalentity",nuixlegalentity);
    return eventContext.getMessage();
}

}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you're using this class as a resource with the Jersey transport. In that case, Mule will call the JAX-RS annotated methods, based on the incoming request, and thus will not call `onCall`. Therefore implementing `Callable` is of no use.

Using `RequestContext.getEventContext()` is the only way possible to get the `EventContext` in a Jersey-handled resource.

To this date, MuleSoft hasn't provided a workable replacement for cases like this one so, even if `RequestContext.getEventContext()` is deprecated, you unfortunately have no other choice than using it.

Comment: Your assumption is correct.
I can not believe there is no other way to store POST attribute whatever into mule message or context.I mean should be a common use case isn't it ?

Comment: I'm not sure I'm following you here: your JAX-RS annotated resource should receive the POST request, i.e. `setMessage` should be called. If not, it's a bug. Please edit your question and add your Mule configuration. Also specify the version.

Comment: Apparently I was trying to do something unfeasible. Since RequestContext.getEventContext() is deprecated there is no way to gather those POST attributes in my web service updating the mule message status. I eventually replaced the web service with a message transformer out of box.

Comment: Apparently,web service in Mulesoft can not be an entry point for your business flow..

Comment: Are you saying that you know how to manipulate data and update the message or context status within a webservice?

Comment: I'm saying you can receive POST attributes in a JAX-RS annotated web-service handled by the Jersey transport.

Comment: And sure `RequestContext.getEventContext()` is deprecated but so far MuleSoft hasn't provided any replacement for cases like yours so you have no other option but to use it.

Comment: Oh, yes we were saying the same thing.